# Rails: Clearing postgres schemas in test database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, multi-tenant

I working through a mutli-tenancy tut using postgres schemas.

The schemas for each tenant in the test database need to be cleared after each run for the tests to run correctly.

rspec produces the following errors

```
An error occurred in an after hook
  PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"
LINE 5:       where nspowner != (select oid from pg_roles where role...


1) account scoping displays only account A's records
  Failure/Error: let!(:account_a) { FactoryGirl.create(:account_with_schema) }
  Apartment::SchemaExists:
    The schema test1 already exists.
  # ./app/models/subscribem/account.rb:20:in `create_schema'
  # ./spec/support/factories/account_factory.rb:11:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
  # ./spec/features/accounts/scoping_spec.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the code attempting to clear out the database after each test.

spec_helper.rb

```
 config.after(:each) do
   Apartment::Database.reset
   DatabaseCleaner.clean
   connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection
   schema = connection.query(%Q{
    SELECT 'drop schema ' || nspname || ' cascade;' 
    from pg_namespace 
    where nspname != 'public' AND 
    where nspowner != (select oid from pg_roles where rolname = 'postgres'); 
   })
   schemas.each do |query|
    connection.query(query.values.first)
   end 
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are a couple of things wrong with your SQL.

Firstly you have two `WHERE` clauses, just use `AND` instead of `AND WHERE`. Secondly you probably need to use `NOT IN` rather than `!=` for your subquery condition.

Try:

```
schema = connection.query(%Q{
  SELECT 'drop schema ' || nspname || ' cascade;' 
  from pg_namespace 
  where nspname != 'public' AND 
  nspowner NOT IN (select oid from pg_roles where rolname = 'postgres'); 
})
```

Comment: Still produces the same error An error occurred in an after hook
  PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"
LINE 5:       where nspowner NOT IN (select oid from pg_roles where ...

Comment: It looks like its still got two `WHERE` clauses, line 5 referred to in the error should be `nspowner NOT IN...` not `where nspowner NOT IN`.